# NavLink with externalLink

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

```
<NavLink target="_blank" to={{ pathname: "mailto:test@gmail.com" }}>
   <h3>Say hi...</h3>
</NavLink>
```

```
<NavLink
          style={{ color: "inherit" }}
          to={{ pathname: "https://github.com/user" }}
          target="_blank"
        >
          <LinkedIn width={30} height={25} fill="currentColor" />
        </NavLink>
```

Here I am using `NavLink` to reach a external Link. But when I click on the link it redirects to
http://localhost:3000/mailto:test@gmail.com.
using `a` instead of `NavLink` is working fine.

Is there any way that it can work with NavLink.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1):

Try sth. like this

```
<NavLink as="a" target="_blank" href="mailto:test@gmail.com">
   <h3>Say hi...</h3>
</NavLink>
```

Comment: on using this code, react throws error

```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')```

Comment: for sure my mistake. updated the answer